# Interpreting the past tense of 形容動詞 / 形容詞 / adjectives

Tags: adjectives, i-adjectives, na-adjectives

In Japanese 形容動詞 can be used as part of a noun phrase in the past tense (contrary to adjectives in English), e.g:

> 「綺麗だった花」 → "the beautiful<sub>past</sub> flower" → "the flower that was beautiful"

We can combine  the noun phrase with a verb phrase, with every combination of past and present tense for either of the verb and the 形容動詞:

> 1. 綺麗な花を買う。
> 2. 綺麗な花を買った。
> 3. 綺麗だった花を買う。
> 4. 綺麗だった花を買った。

I can see the following interpretation of the last three sentences:

2. This can have two interpretations:

   - The flower was beautiful at the time of buying, and may or may not be beautiful at the time of speaking.
   - The flower is beautiful at the time of speaking, and it may or may not have been beautiful at the time of buying.
3. This can have two interpretations:

   - The flower has been beautiful in the past, but no longer is at the time of speaking.
   - The flower was beautiful in the past, and may still be beautiful at the time of speaking.
4. This can have three interpretations:

   - The flower was beautiful at a time before buying, but no longer was at the time of buying, which is before the time of speaking. So to say: *"I bought the flower that **had been** beautiful once."*
   - The flower was beautiful at the time of buying, but no longer is at the time of speaking.
   - The flower was beautiful at a time before buying, and may or may not be at the time of buying, and may or may not be at the time of speaking.

**Question 1**: Are these interpretations grammatical? Am I missing interpretations?

**Question 2**: Are these interpretations natural (i.e. would a fluent speaker interpret them this way)?

**Question 3**: Do 形容詞 work in an equivalent manner? (e.g. 美しかった花を買う, etc.)

Comment: Don’t have time to write a full answer right now, but I’d say this is lacking precision around the time-of-buying vs time-of-speech in the case of the ‘present tense’ matrix verbs, which almost always would actually be interpreted as occurring at a future time (for the sentences as you've written them) — and relatedly, what exactly the embedded predicate’s tense is relative to.